# Symfony FOSJsRoutingBundle installation on Symfony3

Tags: symfony

When trying to add the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#installation) to my new Symfony3 project by:

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle
```

However, this given a stream of errors as below - is this bundle no longer supported? Is there an alternative we should be using?

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.0.0
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
>       - friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle 1.5.0 requires symfony/serializer ~2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/serializer[2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.8.0].

... [truncated]...

> - don't install symfony/serializer v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
>
>   - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.0].
>   - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle ^1.5 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle[1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony 3 was released just about a week ago, its a new major version that contains BC breaks with previous versions where depreciated code will not work.

Your issue is probably due to the fact that so many third party bundles have not updated their code base to be compatible with Symfony 3 and that is why the brilliance of composer has refused to install it for you.

If you plan on using many third party bundles, my advice is that you install Symfony 2.8 where everything should work and install and you will get warnings and notices of depreciated code.

Comment: Thanks good point - it's a nuisance for what I was working on but then I'm sure I can find something out to work on in the meantime...! :-)